# Finding the id's which include multiple criteria in long format

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, relational-division

Suppose I have a table like this,

| id | tagId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 8 |

I want to select **id**'s where **tagId** includes both 2 and 5. For this fake data set, It should return 1 and 3.

I tried,

```
select id from [dbo].[mytable] where tagId IN(2,5)
```

But it takes 2 and 5 into account respectively. I also did not want to keep my table in wide format since tagId is dynamic. It can reach any number of columns. I also considered filtering with two different queries to find (somehow) the intersection. However since I may search more than two values inside the tagId in real life, it sounds inefficient to me.

I am sure that this is something faced before when tag searching. What do you suggest? Changing table format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to count the number of distinct `tagId`s (from the ones you're looking for) each `id` has:

```sql
SELECT   id
FROM     [dbo].[mytable] 
WHERE    tagId IN (2,5)
GROUP BY id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT tagId) = 2
```

Comment: Clever solution.  
Little typo: `DISTINCT`.

Comment: The number 2 at the last step represents  _at least_ condition for the number of the tags I am searching. Right?

Comment: @Zaki indeed a typo, thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed

Comment: @maydin The `where` clause limits the return rows to tagIds of 2 and 5, and then the `having` clause makes sure they are both there. If an ID has additional tags it won't interfere with this query

Answer (score 2):

**This is actually a [*Relational Division With Remainder*](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) question.**

First, you have to place your input into proper table format. I suggest you use a Table Valued Parameter if executing from client code. You can also use a temp table or table variable.

```sql
DECLARE @ids TABLE (tagId int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @ids VALUES (2), (5);
```

There are a number of different solutions to this type of question.

1. Classic double-negative `EXISTS`

   ```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT
     mt.Id
   FROM mytable mt
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
       FROM @ids i
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM mytable mt2
           WHERE mt2.id = mt.id
             AND mt2.tagId = i.tagId)
   );
   ```

   This is not usually efficient though
2. Comparing to the total number of IDs to match

   ```sql
   SELECT mt.id
   FROM mytable mt
   JOIN @ids i ON i.tagId = mt.tagId
   GROUP BY mt.id
   HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ids);
   ```

   This is much more efficient. You can also do this using a window function, it may be more or less efficient, YMMV.

   ```sql
   SELECT mt.Id
   FROM mytable mt
   JOIN (
       SELECT *,
         total = COUNT(*) OVER ()
       FROM @ids i
   ) i ON i.tagId = mt.tagId
   GROUP BY mt.id
   HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(i.total);
   ```
3. Another solution involves cross-joining everything and checking how many matches there are using conditional aggregation

   ```sql
   SELECT mt.id
   FROM (
       SELECT
         mt.id,
         mt.tagId,
         matches = SUM(CASE WHEN i.tagId = mt.tagId THEN 1 END),
         total = COUNT(*)
       FROM mytable mt
       CROSS JOIN @ids i
       GROUP BY
         mt.id,
         mt.tagId
   ) mt
   GROUP BY mt.id
   HAVING SUM(matches) = MIN(total)
      AND MIN(matches) >= 0;
   ```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9512594a18be4058cf2f5e14cd3b4a44)

There are other solutions also, see [High Performance Relational Division in SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/)

Comment: This is very informative. Thank you @Charlieface . I wish I have a chance to accept two answers together. But upvoted!